# Spring boot basic auth always gives 401 error

Tags: http, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have configured spring boot security, by adding the dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

I have also added These properties in yml:

```
security:
 user: user
 Password: user
```

And am using postman,
 my URL to secure is:

```
http://localhost:8080/api
```

and am adding authorization : type is Basic Auth and username is user and Password is user are also added

But everytime i do Get on this URL, i get 401 unauthorized error.

Please any help is great

Comment: Where is your yml file located? I tend to use the following structure for basic authentication: http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();

Comment: thanks i tried similar way and it works

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the settings in your `application.yml` as follows:

```
spring:
  name:
    user: user
    password: user
```

BTW, you may see following message in your console output after starting up your application if the configuration hasn't been read correctly:

> Using default security password: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Hope this helps to you!